# Volunteers entering paper based memberships

Tags: wordpress, civimember

Looking for an answer for a question I asked a year and a half ago but not resolved.

Using Wordpress and CiviCRM 4.7.27

We have a number of volunteers who are not very computer literate and we do not want to give these volunteers access to the back end. We collect paper-based memberships at events and activities. The members pay us on site. We want our volunteers to enter those memberships right after the events and have the membership contribution shown as complete because we've received the money.

The initial direction I took was to create a membership contribution page with a profile with the additional info we usually ask people to enter when they do an online sign up themselves. Then directed the volunteers to use that web page to enter the information shown on the paper membership. I had no choice but to tell the volunteers to use the pay later option when recording the membership as there's no way I'm aware of through a payment processor to indicate that the payment was provided upon time of purchase. Our other payment method is PayPal.

Everything gets recorded properly except that the contribution status is pending. So now the volunteers send me an email saying they've entered the memberships and I go into the back end to show them as complete.

Is there another way to do this with the results I want? I've played with the batch membership profile as per [Use contribution page to record memberships at event](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11846/use-contribution-page-to-record-memberships-at-event) but I think that's meant to be used on the back end?

Anyone else attempting to do this who's found a solution?

Comment: Found a solution by adding a CiviRule. Trigger Contribution is Added, Condition a custom "Entered By" field contains something (it's a mandatory field for a volunteer to complete with their name), Action contribution is marked complete. Had to add that action to the CiviRule extension and then clear the cache for everything to work.

Comment: Great solution, make it an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: Unfortunately not working exactly as I expected after more testing. So still an issue.

Comment: If you describe your solution in more detail along with the issues you face, you may get some further help.

Comment: You might like to take a look at "Permissions and Access Control" at this link https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/   There you can define a role for an individual and give permissions to take certain actions.

Comment: We want to make it very easy for a volunteer or someone visiting a kiosk to enter a membership. We don't want them in the back-end. The problem is that you can't do this all in one shot. After you use a contribution page to enter the information and take the money from the individual, you still have to go into the back-end to mark the contribution complete because a cash or money contribution is always marked pending until you go into the back-end to flip the status. I thought I had a solution with CiviRule but can't get it to work properly.